# RoR voting system. How to count up votes, down votes, and total votes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, voting

I am trying to create a voting system. The models that are being voted on are Issues and I have another model called Vote that holds an issue_id and a vote value of 0 or 1. The votes are being created with forms with hidden fields. This is on the issues index view.

```
<h1>Votes</h1>
```

```
<% @issues.each do |issue| %>
<li>
    <div class="issue">
        <h2><%= issue.title %></h2>
        <p><%= issue.body %></p>

        <%= form_for(@vote, :remote => true) do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field "issue_id", :value => issue.id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field "vote", :value => 1 %>
        <%= submit_tag "Up", :class => 'up-vote' %>
        <% end %>


        <%= form_for(@vote, :remote => true) do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field "issue_id", :value => issue.id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field "vote", :value => 0 %>
       <%= submit_tag "Down", :class => 'down-vote' %>
        <% end %>

    </div>
</li>
<% end %>
```

There is a has_many and belongs_to relationship between issues and votes. I want to display the number of up votes and down votes next to the buttons for each issue. So I need to pull all the votes with vote = 1 for each issue, as well as all the ones with vote = 0, and count each. Also want to know total votes. How should I do this? I have counter_cache set on the vote models issue association and votes_count column in my issues schema. Should this work be done in the controller or the model?

Comment: i don't think what i'm about to link to is the same thing as you're trying to construct ... but it might help out, maybe? here's the link: http://railscasts.com/episodes/364-active-record-reputation-system ... came across it when i was perusing their site. kind of new to the whole ruby/rails thing. anyway, hope it helps out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but you should try adding some methods to your `Issue` model like this:

```
def upvote_count
  votes.count(:conditions => "value = 1")
end

def downvote_count
  votes.count(:conditions => "value = 0")
end
```

I learned this in the Rails documentation.  You can see for yourself here:

http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionAssociation/count

Comment: I tried this but I keep getting undefined method errors when I try to use them in the view.

Comment: I can't help you without the exact error message and knowing what line it happened on.  Did you put the methods in the Issue class?

Comment: figured out my problem. I was using @issue.upvote_count instead of issue.upvote_count. I have another problem though. The functions keep returning 0 when I use votes.count(:conditions => "vote = 1"). Here's what I'm seeing in the console: 

'<Vote id: 27, issue_id: 5, member_id: nil, vote: true, created_at: "2012-10-01 05:43:08", updated_at: "2012-10-01 05:43:08">

1.9.3p194 :005 > @issue.votes.count(:conditions => "vote = 1")
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."issue_id" = 5 AND (vote = 1)
 => 0'

Comment: well the generated query is correct.  Are you sure you actually saved that Vote object to the database?

Comment: No, I think that might be my problem. In my IssuesController index action I have @vote = Vote.new(params[:vote]). Should that be create instead?

Comment: You should do Vote.create in some action that the user goes to when he clicks the up vote or downvote button.

Comment: I moved this to a new question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680437/ror-voting-system-counting-votes-by-condition-vote-true-or-vote-false-not-w

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord has a `count` method that should do what you want: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count

For example, in your controller:

```
@upvotes_count = Vote.count(:conditions => "issue_id = #{@issue.id} AND value = 1")
@downvotes_count = Vote.count(:conditions => "issue_id = #{@issue.id} AND value = 0")
@allvotes_count = Vote.count(:conditions => "issue_id = #{@issue.id}")
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid fetching records from the DB, what's your proposed alternative?

Comment: That won't fetch records from the DB. It'll do an SQL count exactly as you have it. The only difference is that the code will be shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to store votes by their own? If you don't have any other constraint, you'd do with two fields: `upvotes` and `downvotes`. Then you define two actions, "upvote" and "downvote" which update the corresponding field by 1. You can do it atomically, using something like

(model)

```
class Issue < AR::Base

  def self.upvote(id)
    self.where(:id => id).update_all("upvotes = upvotes + 1")
  end

  def self.downvote(id)
    self.where(:id => id).update_all("downvotes = downvotes + 1")
  end

end
```

(controller)

```
class IssuesController < ApplicationController

  def upvote
    Issue.upvote(params[:id])
  end

  def downvote
    Issue.upvote(params[:id])
  end

end
```

(router)

```
resources :issues do
  member do
    post :upvote
    post :downvote
  end
end
```

(view - haml)

```
= form_tag upvote_issue_path(@issue) do
  = submit_tag "Up"
= form_tag downvote_issue_path(@issue) do
  = submit_tag "Down"
```

Comment: thanks for this. I learned a lot. I want to add the ability for users to own votes and pull up vote records by user too however so I think I need the seperate model.